# Show a variable's value in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm currently working on a capstone project for a Java class and a problem I'm coming across frequently is displaying a variable's value in a JavaFX scene. I need a kickstart to get me moving, my google searches aren't bearing any fruit.

Thanks all :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! 
Don't hesitate on looking thru the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) or in 
the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to be sure about how to ask questions. 
Remember to add all code, pseudocode, failed attempts, error logs and everything in your question as plain text, so we can provide better help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Label`. Attach it to your scene and call `Label.setText(String text)` with the string representation of your variable value. Here's a complete example, using a `Label`:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class main3 extends Application {
    static Integer variable = 250; // The value will be displayed in the window

    @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label variableLabel = new Label();
        variableLabel.setFont(new Font(30));
        variableLabel.setText("" + variable);
        variableLabel.setLayoutX(175);
        variableLabel.setLayoutY(125);

        Group group = new Group(variableLabel);
        Scene scene = new Scene(group, 400, 300);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch();
    }
}
```

Result

[image]

Comment: This was helpful. Is there a way to do it with an MVC format? I tried setting the Label's text to the desired outcome, it compiles but then doesn't actually show in the Scene when I run it.

Comment: @Matthew-Johnson833 What do you mean by MVC format? Are you referring to [Multiview Video Coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiview_Video_Coding), or did you invent an acronym?